# Запуск тестов в зависимости от результата предыдущей функции Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Подскажие, как реализовать такой процесс запуска тестов (Pyton, Selenium Webdriver, использую pytest): есть функция, которая смотрит, какой элемент расположен на странице: если элемент А, то после этой функции должна запускаться функция (или тест), проверяющий именно элемент А, если же на сранице элемент В, тогда должна запускать другая функция(или тест), проверяющий именно элемент В.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

@pytest.mark.skipif – позволяет задать условие при выполнении которого тест будет пропущен. Взято с хабра https://habr.com/ru/post/269759/